# electron app should run as a background process in windows after startup

Tags: electron

openAsHidden attribute of app.setLoginItemSettings work only with MAC. Then how does electron built apps like Slack startup as hidden and only shows up in the system tray on windows? Which method do they use?

Is there a way with which I can determine if the app is opened by system startup or by the user, so I can use the window.hide() and window.show() accordingly with dom-ready event.

I have tried following way to achieve it:

```js
app.on("ready", async () => {
  app.setLoginItemSettings({
    openAtLogin: true,
    openAsHidden: true,
    path: exeName,
    args: [
      "--processStart",
      `"${exeName}"`,
      "--process-start-args",
      `"--hidden"`
    ]
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This check works:

```
var isLaunchedOnStartup = process.argv.indexOf("--hidden") !== -1;
```

and inside `app.ready`

```
if (isLaunchedOnStartup === true) {
  createWindow();
  mainWindow?.hide();
} else {
  createWindow();
  mainWindow?.show();
}
```

and by default BrowserWindow should be hidden:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({show: false});
```